# python: Convert string to class object

Tags: python, string

The following code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
temp_text=A(1,2)
```

If i want to `get temp_text.a`.
How could i get this from a string "a"?
such as :temp_text."a"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the function `getattr` for this:

```
getattr(temp_text, 'a')
```

Comment: Also note that you can call methods this way : `getattr(myobject, 'method_name')(argument1, argument2)`

Comment: OMG, it worked, i searched 2 hours and had no answer

Comment: google: "python get attribute by string" and click first link :)